# Consequences of Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Q. Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function on $[0,1]$ satisfying $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $$\min _{[0,1]} f=-M<0$$ Prove that there exists $c \in(0,1)$ such that
$$f^{\prime \prime}(c) \geq 8 M$$

My attempt:
Suppose $f(h)=-M \quad$ for some $h \in(0,1)$, Then Mean Value Theorem gives $$f^{\prime}\left(c_{1}\right)=\frac{-M-0}{h-0}=\frac{-M}{h}$$ for some $c_{1} \in(0,1)$ and $$f^{\prime}\left(c_{2}\right)=\frac{0-(-M)}{1-h}=\frac{M}{1-h},$$ for some $c_{2} \in(0,1)$. Again, by Mean Value theorem
$\begin{aligned} f^{\prime \prime}(c^*) &=\frac{\left(\frac{M}{1-h}+\frac{M}{h}\right)}{c_{2}-c_{1}} \\ & \geqslant \frac{M}{1-h}+\frac{M}{h} \\ & \geqslant M+M \\ & \geqslant 2 M, \text { for some } c^{*} \in(0,1) \end{aligned}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c \in [0, 1]$ such that $f(c) = -M$. In particular, we know that $f'(c) = 0$. By Lagrange remainder theorem (Taylor expansion), we see that
\begin{align}
f(1)= f(c)+f'(c)(1-c)+\frac{1}{2!}f''(\xi_c)(1-c)^2
\end{align}
for some $\xi_c \in (c, 1)$ or equivalently
\begin{align}
\frac{2M}{(1-c)^2} = f''(\xi_c).
\end{align}
Likewise, we see that
\begin{align}
f(0)= f(c)-f'(c)c+\frac{1}{2!}f''(\xi_c')c^2
\end{align}
where $\xi_c' \in (0, c)$ and
\begin{align}
\frac{2M}{c^2}=f''(\xi_c').
\end{align}

Then either $c\le \frac{1}{2}$ or $1-c\le \frac{1}{2}$. Hence we have the desired result.